# Jquery UI Sortable with Symfony , sending updates to database

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-ui

I am trying to add the Jquery UI Sortable behaviour to an existing table (which is populated through a JavaScript Code).I think I followed the right steps from this link [Using Jquery UI sortable to sort table rows](http://edusagar.com/articles/view/57/Sorting-table-rows-using-Jquery-UI-sortable), yet the order never changes, it's as if the controller function is never called. Here is my code

This is the code in my twig

```
 <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2" data-sort="none">{{ 'element.single'|trans }}<span class="required"> *</span></th>
                            <th class="col-md-2"data-sort="none">{{ 'operation.type.single'|trans }}<span class="required"> *</span></th>
                            <th class="col-md-4" data-sort="none">{{ 'inspection.point.label'|trans }}<span class="required"> *</span></th>
                            <!--09:26-----edit-->
                            <th class="col-md-2" data-sort="none">{{ 'inspection.point.referenceValue'|trans }}</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2" data-sort="none">
                                {#bouton import des gammes d'opérations #}
                                {% if 'inspection_sheet_edit' != app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
                                    {% if is_granted('INSPECTIONSHEET_IMPORT',equipment) %}
                                        <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" name="import">
                                                <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                                                <span>{{ 'import'|trans }}</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tabledivbody" ></tbody>
                </table>

<script>
    var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    }
    $("#tabledivbody").sortable({
        items: "tr",
        cursor: 'move',
        opacity: 0.6,
        helper: fixHelper,
        update: function() {
            sendOrderToServer();
        }

     });

    function sendOrderToServer() {
        var order = $("#tabledivbody").sortable("serialize");
        var test='console text';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", dataType: "json", url: "{{ path('post_order')    }}",
            data: order,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    console.log(test);
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                } else {
                    alert('Some error occurred');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is the function in my controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/post_order", name="post_order")
     */
    public function updateInspectionPointOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = json_decode($request->request->get('request'));
        $count=1;
        foreach ($data->getPoints() as $point) {
            //$count++;
            $em->getRepository('EpxInspectionBundle:InspectionPoint')->updateDisplayOrderInspectionPoint($count,$point->getId());
            $em->flush();
            $point->setDisplayOrder($count);
            $em->getRepository('EpxInspectionBundle:InspectionPoint')->updateDisplayOrderInspectionPoint($count,$point->getId());
            $em->flush();
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

Any insights please.

Comment: What give you the developper console or the symfony debug bar: are there any ajax calls? what is the response of these calls?

Comment: nothing in the consoles, as if the call is not made at all